# How do you execute a sql file using mysql-ctl

Tags: mysql, cloud9-ide

I am learning how to use mysql with Cloud9, I have a script used to create a default database and tables and loading sample data into the new database. How do I use the mysql-ctl tool to execute a script file?

It connects to a database just fine and I can execute ad-hoc queries without an issue.

Comment: I was able to get the out of the box mysql client to work with a little coercion.

Step 1: Get hostname, use the mysql-ctl tool to get the host name.
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname'

Step 2: use the normal mysql client to execute a script
$>mysql -u {{username}} -h {{hostname}} {{database}} < sample.sql

Comment: You cannot use mysql-ctl to execute the script but you can use the usual mysql command:
`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u username < yourfile.sql`

Comment: You are write, if you answer the question, I will approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use mysql-ctl to execute the script (you can see the source code running `less $(which mysql-ctl)` but you can use the usual mysql client command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u username < yourfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are in 'mysql-ctl' just run 
`source file_name.sql` and your script will run.